# Output lidR li2012 tree segmentation

Tags: r, las, lidr

I am trying to output the result of `li2012` tree segmentation but can't seem to write the new attribute in the original las file or into a new file. This is the code I have:

```r
las = readLAS("path/to/input.las", select = "c", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")
las_1 <- segment_trees(las, li2012(dt1 = 1.4))
writeLAS(las_1, "path/to/output.las")
```

the segment trees line took 2 days to run but I can't view it or use it. and my `writeLAS` code ran through the weekend with no results and no error. Am I trying to create an output correctly. better yet, can I just write it into a new attribute in my original file?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say where you made an error without a reproducible example. Below a reprex, it works just as expected.

```r
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package = "lidR")
las_1 <- readLAS(LASfile)
las_1 <- segment_trees(las_1, li2012(dt1 = 1.4))
f <- tempfile(fileext = ".las")
writeLAS(las_1, f)
las_2 = readLAS(f)
head(las_2$treeID)
#> [1]  79  79  79  79  79 124
```

That being said `li2012` is known to me slow. This is inherent to the method described in the paper